# Suppress the processing of all images

Tags: graphics, draft

I am trying to make a draft by forcing LaTeX to ignore all images. How do I tell LaTeX to suppress all the image filenames (in the `\includegraphics` command) and just insert an empty box? The problem with the `[draft]` options is that it still requires me to have all images in the folder where I have my `.tex` files.

Comment: I took the liberty to change 'figure' to 'image' to avoid confusion with the `figure` environment. You apparently want only suppress the `\includegraphics`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from  [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 27):

```
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
```

will give a black box for all images. All absolute width/height settings are recognized.

Comment: If `graphicx` is loaded by another package or document class (e.g. `beamer`) then you can add `\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}` before `\documentclass` to get around the `option class` error.

Comment: but could it not read the width/height from the image, just replace the content with black? I did not use absolute settings and when preparing `demo` the sizes are messed up

Comment: use option `draft`. `demo` is only for testing a document where you do not have the image

Comment: That just doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 21):

The quickest way I can think of is to simply redefine the command:

```
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{\fbox{}}
```

will get you an empty box;

```
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{\fbox{#2}}
```

will get you a box with the intended filename inside it. If you need, say, a specific size box, you can mess around with similar boxmaking commands in place of `\fbox` until you have it doing what you need. But the important thing is: anytime you want a command to do something different than what it does, `\renewcommand`! :)