# Turning off and on images in figures

Tags: graphics, floats, draft

Is it possible to prevent the contents of a figure from being rendered? I have a large book document, and to speed up compiling while working on a draft, I would like to have some way of ignoring the content of the images, but ensuring that the figure size remains.

In several cases I am using a line like:

```
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figure.pdf}
```

so I do not know the actual size of the image.

Comment: Related: [How to replace all pictures by white rectangles?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30255/5764)

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You can either  give the `draft` flag to the `documentclass` which has other implications as it gives the `draft` option to packages called (although some of them may ignore it).

Alternatively, calling the `graphicx` package with the draft option should just do what you want.

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
```

or

```
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
```

If however, while in draft mode you want to see one of the graphics without adding them all in the output, you can unset the draft mode on a per file basis by setting `draft` to `false` as follows:

```
\includegraphics[draft=false]{image.pdf}
```

Comment: @celenius: It still reads the correct image size from the image files and generates a dummy placeholder with the same size. There is also the `demo` option which will not look for any images files and insert some fixed-size replacement.

Comment: For more on the `demo` option, please see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21924/suppress-the-processing-of-all-images

Comment: The option `[draft]`clashes with several other packages like colordvi` and `verbatim`...

Answer (score 8):

You can use the package [`draftfigure`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/draftfigure) to get the same result and modify the display of the switched off figure:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[allfiguresdraft]{draftfigure}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=50pt]{example-image-a}

\includegraphics[draft=false,width=50pt]{example-image-b}

\setdf{content={This figure is switched off.}}
\includegraphics[width=50pt]{example-image-c}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Overleaf, the draft compile mode stops images from being rendered. This also produces a couple of unharmful warnings.

[image]

I hope this helps.