# box instead of picture in sharelatex

Tags: graphics, sharelatex, output, draft

```
\section{Software Architecture}
Hello
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics{SystemOverview.pdf}
\end{figure}
Hallo
```

results in:

[image]

I'm using packages

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ae}
\usepackage{icomma}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[square, numbers, sort]{natbib}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fncychap}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[breaklinks,pdfpagelabels=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
```

and document class

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: Do you have `draft` as an option to the documentclass or `graphicx` package?

Comment: See for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51893/turning-off-and-on-images-in-figures or http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49283/586

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. no, no options set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `\includegraphics` seems to look from the root instead of relative to the code, so if you specify `\includegraphics{folderwithfigures\systemoverview}` it should work. Also pdf and svg does not seem to work, but png does.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you are compiling in "draft" instead of "normal" mode. You can switch between these options in the dropdown menu of the compile button.

Draft mode will enable you to compile faster, but it won't load images.