# Import R plot in Latex

Tags: floats, texmaker, plot, r, import

I am trying to import plot from R to LaTeX, in R, I used:

```
plot()
dev.print(device=pdf, file="price.pdf")
dev.off()
```

Then, in LaTeX, simply used

```
\begin{figure}[ht!]
  \caption{Price} 
  \includegraphics[scale= 0.3]{price.pdf}
  \label{fig:price}    \centering  
\end{figure}
```

However, because of the size of the plot, LaTeX becomes so slow when I `ViewPDF` that I can not even see the plot coming up. I still have several plots waiting to import, and I am wondering is there any other good way to import large size plot in LaTeX? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that your question is R related. Is it only a problem of the total pdf size (How big)?

Importing a lot of graphics in a pdf is a long process. I usually add the option `draft` to the package `graphicxs` and only compile without when checking the text.

```
% In your preamble
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
```

See [related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51893/turning-off-and-on-images-in-figures)

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try.                                                                       I have got several pdf plots, and they are about 800kb to 1.5Mb.