# Displaying figures in RPD journal template

Tags: graphics, templates, eps

I am having some difficulty getting figures to display when using the Radiation Protection Dosimetry (RPD) template ([Link to zip](http://www.oxfordjournals.org/our_journals/rpd/for_authors/Rpd_TeX.zip)).

I understand that the template is designed to work with `*.eps` files.

The following snippet is provided in the documentation describing how to include figures (pretty standard):

```
\begin{figure}
\centerline{\includegraphics{fig01.eps}}
\caption{caption\label{fig:01}}
\end{figure}
```

The code compiles without errors and a PDF is generated. LaTeX provides the space for the figure and even places the caption at the bottom of the figure. The figure itself, however, is not displayed.

The resulting PDF looks like this:

[image: Resulting PDF]

The template might be supplied with the `draft` option (not sure), and if so might affect how figures are displayed ([Turning off and on images in figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51893/turning-off-and-on-images-in-figures)). Not sure if this is actually the case and not sure how to switch to `final` mode.

I have managed to use the same `eps` file in other `documentclasses` and it was rendered successfully: So as far as I understand, both my LaTeX installation as well as the figure I want to include are fine.

It would also be nice if I could get the template to work with PDFs.

Thanks.

---

Edit: Miniminal document and log output following removal of `graphics.cfg`

[Log file](http://pastebin.com/mKtnMByN)

MWE for `document.tex`:

```
\documentclass{Rpd}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage[nolist,nohyperlinks]{acronym}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\def\copyrightyear{2004}%

\title[Test]{Test}

\author[]{}
\address{}

\date{Draft}

\maketitle

\begin{figure}%figure1
\centerline{\includegraphics{test}}
\caption{Caption.}\label{fig:01}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you shouldn't use `\centerline` in latex really, but that's not likely to be the problem, try without the extension: `\centering\includegraphics{fig01}`

Comment: Doesn't look like `draft`-mode. In `draft` the figures normally get replaced by placeholders (showing the filename and relative path).

Comment: The template seems horribly old. I don't know that journal and how strict they are about using their template - but I would seriously consider not using it.

Comment: Remove the included package of graphicx and use the one from your LaTeX installation. This fixes the inclusion of images on my machine using your zip-Archive. EDIT: The faulty file is not the package but `graphics.cfg`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks for the quick reply. Have tried without specifying the extension. Same problem persists unfortunately.

Comment: @Skillmon: Indeed doesn't look like the usual draft mode representation. Just thought that maybe the template made some configuration to how graphics are displayed in draft mode.

Will have a look at using my own graphicx package. I'll report back :)

Comment: it is impossible to debug such a a small fragment, please make a small complete document and show the log that you get. Also you could just tdo the translation externally, use the no extension form and convert the .eps to .pdf wth eps2pdf, or any other tool, then pdflatex will use the pdf version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The zip file includes  files `graphics.cfg` and `color.cfg`  which force graphics inclusion and colour to use the back end specials for dvipsone a commercial dvi to postscript convertor from a company no longer in existence.

Just delete those files.

Your log file (which you did not show) of any test file (which you did not post)
would have shown `dvipsone.def` being included and then several warnings about incorrect `\special` being ignored in pdf mode.

Comment: You stole my comment :) But good explanation.

Comment: @Skillmon oh sorry I didn't see the comments (which seems odd looking at the timings) I could remove this if you want to post:-)

Comment: Nah! Your answer is good. Leave it. The purpose of this is to help the one questioning. Doesn't matter who provides the answer. And I weren't able to explain what's wrong with `dvipsone.def`, just figured it's the problem.

Comment: @Skillmon well as I wrote dvipsone.def it's probably easier for me:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Updated my question with a log file and MWE after I removed the cfg file. Still seeing the same issue unfortunately.

Comment: Got it working after also deleting color.cfg

Comment: @DavidCarlisle and Skillmon Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @SO_tourist oh same thing, I'll update answer thanks