# Compile a LaTeX file ignoring missing EPS graphics

Tags: graphics

I am proofreading a paper for someone else.  I have the `.tex` file but no EPS graphics files. I would like to make a PDF file to read the changes in text that I made, but I keep getting errors because it can't find any of the graphic files.  Can I create a PDF file by ignoring the graphics?

Comment: essentially duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21924/suppress-the-processing-of-all-images

Answer (score 11):

```
 \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
```

will replace every image by a rule. You get a warning but no error for missing files.